# Encoding NSViewController for Lion's user interface resume feature

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, appkit, resume, nsarchiving

Any idea what are the best practices for archiving an `NSViewController` inside a window for [resume](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/CocoaApplicationLayer/CocoaApplicationLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001067-CH274-SW8) (user interface preservation) purposes? I've tried archiving it in the window controller's  `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` methods only to find out that the view controller doesn't get unarchived when  `restoreStateWithCoder:` is called.

```
// NSWindowController subclass

-(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
    NSViewController* contentViewController = self.contentViewController;
    if (contentViewController) {
        [coder encodeObject:contentViewController forKey:BSContentViewControllerResumeKey];
    }
}

-(void)restoreStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [super restoreStateWithCoder:coder];
    NSViewController* contentViewController = [coder decodeObjectForKey:BSContentViewControllerResumeKey];
    if (contentViewController) {
        // somehow this never get executed since contentViewController always comes out nil
        self.contentViewController = contentViewController;
    }
}
```

Note that this view controller contains other view controllers that manages their own subviews, and thus will need some scoping in the `NSCoder` instance – simply passing the provided `coder` object downwards will cause name clashes in the archive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be using using secure coding, did you try `-decodeObjectOfClass:forKey:` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

State restoration works for free on `NSView` but is ignored on `NSViewController` even though it implements the methods as a subclass of `NSResponder`. I suppose that's because the window doesn't know about NSViewControllers that may own some of the views it contains.

On OS X Yosemite it's supposed to work since `NSWindow` now has real support for NSViewControllers, but it doesn't in my test cases. I guess it's because one needs to "chain" the NSViewControllers using the new APIs to add / remove them vs creating them on the side and just adding their views directly to the window. The latter is actually required if you want to have your app run on pre-Yosemite systems anyway.

Here's how to make it always work: simply proxy the restoration APIs calls between `NSView` and `NSViewController`.

Subclass `NSView` like this:

```
@interface GIView : NSView
@property(nonatomic, weak) GIViewController* viewController;  // Avoid retain-loops!
@end

@implementation GIView

- (void)setViewController:(GIViewController*)viewController {
  _viewController = viewController;
}

- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
  [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

  [_viewController encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}

- (void)restoreStateWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
  [super restoreStateWithCoder:coder];

  [_viewController restoreStateWithCoder:coder];
}

@end
```

And `NSViewController` like this:

```
@interface GIViewController : NSViewController
@end

@implementation GIViewController

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
  if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
    self.view.viewController = self;  // This loads the view immediately as a side-effect
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  self.view.viewController = nil;  // In case someone is still retaining the view
}

- (void)invalidateRestorableState {
  [self.view invalidateRestorableState];
}

@end
```

Now you can call `-invalidateRestorableState` from the `NSViewController` subclass and Cocoa, thinking it's talking to an `NSView`, will automatically call `-encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` and `-restoreStateWithCoder:` on your `NSViewController` subclass as needed.

Comment: Hi, this is a nice trick :) I'm trying to implement restoration on a mac app as well and I'm not getting the restoration calls even for the NSView subclasses. Any idea what that could be? I created a new thread for that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42010026/3251155

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t messed with restorable state much (Jonathon Mah did it for DL3) but if I were doing this I’d try deleting those two methods and implement +restorableStateKeyPaths, e.g.:

```
+ (NSArray *)restorableStateKeyPaths;
{
    return @[@“contentViewController.firstInterestingStateProperty”, @“contentViewController.secondInterestingStateProperty”];
}
```

And just see if the machinery handled it all for me.

```
+ (NSArray *)restorableStateKeyPaths;
```

> Returns a set of key paths, representing paths of properties that
>   should be persistent.  The frameworks will observe these key paths via
>   KVO and automatically persist their values as part of the persistent
>   state, and restore them on relaunch.  The values of the key paths
>   should implement keyed archiving.  The base implementation returns an
>   empty array.

Comment: This would work if `contentViewController` is the same class (thus same set of restorable properties) for the window controller. Unfortunately the view controller is swappable among a good number of classes. Think the official Twitter app, with swappable views depending of what you've selected in the left "tab" bar. Similarly the view controllers are also swappable as according to the top level views that they control.