# NSViewControllers and NSViews are not getting restoration API calls

Tags: macos, state-restoration

in Apple's documentation they say that in case of document-based apps you should get restoration calls (restoreStateWithCoder: and encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:) to NSApplication, NSWindow, NSWindowController and then the whole responder chain ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH5-SW8)).

I want to implement this, but I'm getting the restoration calls  only in NSWindowController/NSDocument subclass, not the NSViews or NSViewControllers.

I created a new document-based app to test this ([here](https://github.com/psmejkal/macos-restoration-api-test)), but I get the restoration calls only in the NSDocument subclass but not the NSViewController or NSView.

Code from the test project:

NSDocument subclass (restoration works):

```
class Document: NSDocument {

  override func restoreState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    super.restoreState(with: coder)
    // Gets called after reopening the app
  }

  override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
    // Gets called when leaving the window for the first time
  }


}
```

NSViewController subclass (restoration doesn't work):

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

  override func restoreState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    super.restoreState(with: coder)
    // Not called
  }

  override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
    // Not called
  }

}
```

NSView subclass (restoration doesn't work):

```
class MyView: NSView {

  override func restoreState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    super.restoreState(with: coder)
    // Not called
  }

  override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
    // Not called
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `invalidateRestorableState`? It's barely mentioned in Apple's description of the restoration machinery and not mentioned at all in the description of `encodeRestorableState` so it's easy to overlook (or at least it was for me for the last half hour).

Comment: Same problem here. Did you finally figure out what the problem was?

Comment: same problem here

Comment: Same problem. Wasted hours already.

Comment: @actual I posted an answer. Let me know if it still does not work!

Comment: @CharltonProvatas I posted an answer.

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same problem. It seems the state preservation system uses the [`identifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsuserinterfaceitemidentification/1396829-identifier) property to determine whether to encode/restore the state of an object.

According to the documentation, the identifier is automatically populated when an object is loaded from a NIB file. However, it needs to be set manually if an object is created programmatically.